# How do i dynamic add textarea and also auto expand

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a question about the dynamic add text area with auto expand. I have research on text area auto expand and I success. It can be using in the text area that is on load but how do I also make it on dynamic add text area also can be auto expand. I have used keyup event but it didnt success

Here is used for test [Testing Here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27321/)

//here is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        //dynamic create mutiple inputbox
        var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

        var x = 0; //initlal text box count
        $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                //$(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
                $(wrapper).append(

                  '<div class="panel panel-default product_wrapper">'+
                        '<div class="panel-heading">'+
                            '<h4 class="panel-title">'+
                                '<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#product'+x+'">Product'+x+'</a>'+
                            '</h4>'+
                        '</div>' +

                        '<div id="product'+x+'" class="panel-collapse collapse in">'+
                            '<div class="panel-group">'+
                                '<div class="panel panel-default">'+

                                    '<div class="col-lg-12">' +

                                        '<div class="col-lg-3" >' +
                                            '<label>Product</label>' +
                                            '<textarea type="text" class="product_textarea" name="Product[]"></textarea>' +
                                        '</div>' +

                                        '<div class="col-lg-6">' +
                                            '<label>Description</label>' +
                                            '<textarea rows="5"  name="ProductDescription[]"></textarea>' +
                                        '</div>' +

                                        '<div class="col-lg-2 form-group">' +
                                            '<label>Price</label>' +
                                            '<input type="text" class="price_tag form-control" name="Price[]"/>' +
                                        '</div>' +                                            
                                    '</div>'+

                                '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+

                        '</div>'+
                        '<a href="#" class="remove_field btn btn-danger pull-right">cancel</a>' +
                    '</div>'

                  );
            }
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('.product_wrapper').remove();
            calculateTotal();
            x--;
        })

        $('textarea').each(function () {
            this.setAttribute('style', 'height:' + (this.scrollHeight) + 'px;overflow-y:hidden;');
        }).on('input', function () {
            this.style.height = 'auto';
            this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px';
        });

    });
```

//here is my view

```
<h2>Product List</h2>

                <div class="panel-group">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Product List</a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in input_fields_wrap">
                            <div class="panel-group">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">                                      

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>

                    <!--<div class="input_fields_wrap">

                    </div>-->

                    <button class="add_field_button btn btn-primary pull-right">Add More Fields</button>

                    <h1>
                    Testing here
                    </h1>
                    <textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `$('textarea')`, it creates a JQuery object that represents all `<textarea>` elements that are on the page **at that time**. Since you are dynamically adding the `<textarea>` elements at a later time, they do not get included when you call:

```
$('textarea').each(function () {
    this.setAttribute('style', 'height:' + (this.scrollHeight) + 'px;overflow-y:hidden;');
}).on('input', function () {
    this.style.height = 'auto';
    this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px';
});
```

You would have to call that code on them after they are added to the page. But you don't want to call it again for `<textarea>` elements that have already been added. You could do this by limiting it to the last div appended to the wrapper:

```
$(wrapper).children(':last').find('textarea').each(function () {
    this.setAttribute('style', 'height:' + (this.scrollHeight) + 'px;overflow-y:hidden;');
}).on('input', function () {
    this.style.height = 'auto';
    this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px';
});
```

Of course, you could use event delegation for the input-event handler, just like you did for the click-event handler for the `.remove_field` links.

Comment: Thx!! it works perfectly. can i ask why need use `.children('.last').find('textarea')` << i didnt fully understand this

Comment: @nonstop328 - That way the code to register the input-event handler applies only to the newly added textareas. If there are any previously added textareas, they already have the input-event handler registered. You don't want to register another event handler again (and again) to those textareas.

Comment: I have a little question, can I also using same as this method for my jquery autocomplete? in each dynamic add textbox

Comment: @nonstop328 - You should be able to use the same method for autocomplete. I use the term "instrumenting" when referring to adding dynamic behavior to an element using event handling. Whenever you dynamically add an element to the page, you need to instrument it, without re-instrumenting the elements that are already on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this after append new textarea to wrapper:

```
$(wrapper).find("textarea").each(function () {
            this.setAttribute('style', 'height:' + (this.scrollHeight) + 'px;overflow-y:hidden;');
      }).on('input', function () {
            this.style.height = 'auto';
            this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px';
      });
```

You can optimize your code to be shorter in the future.

Comment: It works but got 1 problem which is when I collapse the previous product when I open it again will become 1 line only. @John S didn't have this issue. But anyways thx for your answer!